# Inhibit warnings for subspec dependency

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I'm developing a `Pod` that have a external dependency, which shows a lot of warnings in Xcode when using my `Pod` in an App.

What I want to do is remove all those warnings since it could quite annoying to see for those who use my `Pod`.

Is there a way to solve this? I'm trying several parameters in the `subspec.xcconfig` setting but I'm not able to find a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking about one of your pod's subspecs or dependencies?

Comment: I have a dependency inside of one of my subspec that is generating those warnings.